# Are the NEW list and map features of Aerospike limited to row size?

Tags: aerospike

According to Aerospike their previous large data types are deprecated:
http://www.aerospike.com/blog/aerospike-ldt/

However, in the blog posts (also from Aerospike) explaining the replacement capabilities after the ldt's are deprecated it almost seems like these new features are not size restricted.  (Which seems rather odd, since that might have been one of the problems and why Aerospike deprecated the old ones.  Unless I am misunderstanding something.)

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html
"Lists are useful when you are dealing size-bound lists residing in a single bin."

www(dot)aerospike(dot)com/docs/guide/cdt-map(dot)html
"Maps in Aerospike are collections of key/value pairs. They are useful when dealing with a size-bound collection residing in a single bin. Aerospike map operations are optimal for manipulating key-value pairs directly on the Aerospike server. For example, add items, remove an item, or get a range of items by value, can all be done without reading and/or replacing the whole bin value."

So is there anyone who knows the answer?

Thank you in advance. :)

(I gave absolutely no one permission to edit my question and I do not approve of it.)

Comment: There are so many personal remarks in your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general record size restriction applies to list and maps. The largest size of a record is the write-block-size, which can be configured, at this point, to 1MB at most.

Comment: What is the default record size, and if not 1MB, how do I configure it (I don't see it in aerospike.conf). Also did I see somewhere that each bin is a multiple of 128 bytes? So if I have a 129-byte value it takes up 256 bytes? And if I have 2 x 129-byte bins in a record it will take up 512 bytes out of my 1MB allocation?

Comment: The response below should hopefully help you. And of course, 1 write block can hold multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

For Thomas Browne: 1 Mb max is defined by write-block-size  (see http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration for details on write-block-size)

write-block-size is recommended 128Kb for namespaces with SSD.

128 byte: not bins - full record must be multiple of 128 bytes ONLY when namespace storage is defined as device on SSDs because you can only read in 128 byte blocks from an SSD. full record on SSD is not just data size but also overhead. see http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity  to estimate size of record in bytes on SSD.  if record size (data + all overhead) is 129 bytes, on SSD, you will end up using 256 bytes.

Comment: Note: "write-block-size" limit does not apply if you are storing your data purely in memory. So no restriction from a storage point of view on record size if "storage engine memory" is configured for a namespace. You will then be limited in record size on the client side or other buffers along the path. So if you don't care about persistence at all, you can go beyond the 1Mb record size limit!